# variable value not incrementing in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
const qno = document.getElementById("qno");
const exit = document.getElementById("exit");
const qncol = document.getElementById("qncol");
const quiz = document.getElementById("quiz");
const question = document.getElementById("question");
const choice1 = document.getElementById("never");
const choice2 = document.getElementById("rarely");
const choice3 = document.getElementById("often");
const choice4 = document.getElementById("always");
const next = document.getElementById("next");
const analysis=document.getElementById("analysis")

let questions = [
    {
        question : "Having little or no interest in day-to-day actvities!",
        choice1 : "Never",
        choice2 : "Rarely",
        choice3 : "Often",
        choice4 : "Always"
    },
    {
        question : "Do you feel guilty or tearful for no reason?",
        choice1 : "Never",
        choice2 : "Rarely",
        choice3 : "Often",
        choice4 : "Always"
    },{
        question : "Trouble falling or staying asleep, due to nightmares?",
        choice1 : "Never",
        choice2 : "Rarely",
        choice3 : "Often",
        choice4 : "Always"
    },
    {
        question : "You feel depressed even when good things happen to you.",
        choice1 : "Never",
        choice2 : "Rarely",
        choice3 : "Often",
        choice4 : "Always"
    },
];


const lastQuestion = questions.length - 1;
let runningQuestion = 0;
let c1=0;
let c2=0;
let c3=0;
let c4=0;
let scorepos=0;
let scoreneg=0;

function renderQuestion(){
    let q = questions[runningQuestion];    
    question.innerHTML = "<p>"+ q.question +"</p>";
    choice1.innerHTML = q.choice1;
    choice2.innerHTML = q.choice2;
    choice3.innerHTML = q.choice3;
    choice4.innerHTML = q.choice4;
}

start.addEventListener("click",startQuiz);

function startQuiz(){
    next.style.display="block"
    exit.style.display= "block";
    qncol.style.display= "block";
    qno.style.display= "block";
    start.style.display = "none";
    quiz.style.display = "block";
    renderQuestion();

}

//next.addEventListener("click",nextQuestion);
console.log(c1);
//function nextQuestion(){}

function storeAnswer(answer){
    if( answer == questions[runningQuestion].choice1){
        c1++;
        console.log(c1);
    }else if( answer == questions[runningQuestion].choice2){
        c2++;
        console.log(c2);
    }else if( answer == questions[runningQuestion].choice3){
        c3++;
        console.log(c3);
    }else if( answer == questions[runningQuestion].choice4){
        c4++;
        console.log(c4);
    }

    scorepos=c1+c2;
    scoreneg=c3+c4;
    console.log(c1);
    if(runningQuestion < lastQuestion){
        runningQuestion++;
        return renderQuestion();
    }else{
        next.style.display="none"
        qncol.style.display= "none";
        quiz.style.display = "none";
        return graphRender(scorepos,scoreneg);
    }
}
```

when I run the function, it does not increment c1,c2,c3,c4 values. The console shows 0 as my answer. I am not sure where the error is occuring because when my html page executes this javascript file, the remaining code in the function is executed except for the increment of variables.
So the js file has questions of the quiz, which it renders in the html page, now i want to make an analysis, so thats why i introduce 4 variables, which will store the number of clicks on each option. which can then be used to render graphs on the html page.

Comment: We have no idea what `answer` or `questions` data are to step though this with. Take some time to read up on creating a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The value passing from the HTML page on click might be wrong, thats why the value is not incrementing.
Please check the HTML code where in you are printing the choices and calling the function on "onclick".